# How can I move/copy multiple file at once with different extension in cmd window?

Tags: cmd.exe

For example, I have 4 files with different extension like

1. File1.txt
2. File2.xlsx
3. File3.pdf
4. image.jpg

I have to copy/move these four files at once.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What OS  etc., etc.? Windows command prompt a simple "copy *.*" would work I assume. copy star dot star (stars disappear once I save this comment).

Answer (score 1):

```
copy "source" "destination"
```

When writing "source" use wildcards

```
for example copy c:\*.*  d:\
```

Will copy all files from drive c to d regardles of name and extension.

```
Copy c:\file*.* d:\
```

Would copy all files with name starting with file regardles of extension.

```
Copy c:\$$.* d:\
```

Would copy all files with name consisting of only 2 characters

Wildcards:

"*" - stands for multiple characters

"$" - stands for one character

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Robocopy**.

**Syntax:**

```
robocopy source destination [file [file]...]
```

So for example to **copy** your files from folder `D:\MyData` to folder `E:\Test` you can use:

```
robocopy D:\MyData E:\Test File1.txt File2.xlsx File3.pdf image.jpg
```

To **move** the files, use option `/MOV`, like so:

```
robocopy D:\MyData E:\Test File1.txt File2.xlsx File3.pdf image.jpg /MOV
```